# Evenly intermix two lists of elements (load balance)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sequence, load-balancing

Let's say I have two strings made with only 1 character:

```
'aaaaaaa'
'bbb'
```

I'd like to find an algorithm to produce a combined string of:

```
'aabaabaaba'
```

The two are merged so that there is the fewest # of consecutive characters from either list (in this case that # is 2). The length of each string is arbitrary, and I'd like for it to be symmetrical. Bonus points for extending it to more than just 2 strings.

I am doing this in python, but the language doesn't matter. This is for a load balancing problem I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools

def intermix(*containers):
    mix = []
    for c in sorted(containers, key=lambda c: len(c)):
        if len(c) >= len(mix):
            bigger, smaller = c, mix
        else:
            bigger, smaller = mix, c
        ratio, remainder = divmod(len(bigger), len(smaller) + 1)
        chunk_sizes = (ratio + (1 if i < remainder else 0) for i in range(len(smaller) + 1))
        chunk_offsets = itertools.accumulate(chunk_sizes)
        off_start = 0
        new_mix = []
        for i, off in enumerate(chunk_offsets):
            new_mix.extend(bigger[off_start:off])
            if i == len(smaller):
                break
            new_mix.append(smaller[i])
            off_start = off
        mix = new_mix
    return mix
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the elements alternatively and use a letter of the longer string if necessary. You can determine whether an additional letter is possible with integer arithmetics: A fraction tells you how many letters come between each letter pair. You accumulate this fraction and use letters from the longer array as long as that accumulated fraction is larger than ½:

```
def intertwine(a, b):
    """ Return a combination of string with fewest number of
        consecutive elements from one string
    """

    if len(b) > len(a):
        return intertwine(b, a)

    if not b:
        return a

    a = list(a)
    b = list(b)

    num = len(a) - len(b)
    denom = len(b)
    acc = 0

    res = []

    while a or b:
        acc += num

        while acc >= denom / 2:
            if a: res += a.pop(0)
            acc -= num

        if a: res += a.pop(0)
        if b: res += b.pop(0)

    return "".join(res)



print intertwine("aaabaaa", "bbb")      # "aababbaaba"
print intertwine("aaaaaaa", "b")        # "aaabaaaa"
print intertwine("aaaaaa", "b")         # "aaabaaa"
print intertwine("aa", "bbbbbb")        # "bbabbabb"
print intertwine("", "bbbbbb")          # "bbbbbb"
print intertwine("", "")                # ""
```